# django-crontab works manually but not automatically

Tags: django, cron

I hope i could get some help I have installed the django-crontab and created a cron task like the following inside of my cron.py inside my_django_app in django:

```
import redis
def hello():
    redis.set("hello", "world")
```

the above code works perfectly when I run **python manage.py crontab run (cron hash)***
and the key set successfully inside redis but the task doesn't run automatically have you had any similar experience?
Note: I am using linux and python version 3.9 and django 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick steps:

1. Use `crontab -l` to get the actural command the crontab will execute, for example:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your_django_project/manage.py crontab run (cron hash)
```

2. Execute the command **outside of your project directory**, for example, in the home directory `~`, this step is very important, the reason will be explained below
3. You might see an error message which could help you figure out the problem in your case

#### The full situation is below:

I have a similar experience recently. The scheduled function works successfully when I run `python manage.py crontab run (cron hash)` command manually. However, the scheduled function does not work without any error log or error message if the command was executed by the crontab.

Luckily, I see an error message when I go to another directory and execute the command again. I realize that the scheduled function could work because I execute the command in my project directory `/path/to/my_django_project`.

In my case, the problem is that I use a relative path to load a file. It works when I execute the command in my project directory, however, the file could not be found by the crontab because **the working directory of crontab is the owner's home directory by default**, which is not my project directory. I resolve the problem by using an absolute path for the file.